# Request Response JSON in magento 2

Tags: frontend, controllers, magento2.2, json, response

I have modified form review as popup modal and have overrides the controller in my custom module, the review saved successfully in DB. I need to pass the response to the to JS in JSON format , Help me how to solve it.
Here I have given my custom controller but it shows error while compiling

> Errors during compilation:    XXX\YYY\Controller\Index\Index      Missed
>   required argument coreRegistry in parent::__construct call. File:
>   /var/www/html/magento220/app/code/XXX/YYY/Controller/Index/Index.php
>   Total Errors Count: 1
>
> ```
>                                           [Magento\Framework\Validator\Exception]     Error during compilation
> ```

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace XXX\YYY\Controller\Index;


use Magento\Review\Model\Review;
use Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\JsonFactory;

class Index extends \Magento\Review\Controller\Product\Post
{

    protected $_resultJsonFactory;

    public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $message = null;
        $status = null;
        if (!$this->formKeyValidator->validate($this->getRequest())) {
            $message[] = "Invalid form key";
            $status = 'failed';
        } else {
            $data = $this->reviewSession->getFormData(true);


            if ($data) {
                $rating = [];
                if (isset($data['ratings']) && is_array($data['ratings'])) {
                    $rating = $data['ratings'];
                }
            } else {
                $data = $this->getRequest()->getPostValue();
                $rating = $this->getRequest()->getParam('ratings', []);
            }
            echo 'sdfsdfsdfsdfsd';
            print_r($data);

            if (($product = $this->initProduct()) && !empty($data)) {
                echo 'InsideLoops';
                /** @var \Magento\Review\Model\Review $review */
                $review = $this->reviewFactory->create()->setData($data);

                $review->unsetData('review_id');

                $validate = $review->validate();
                if ($validate === true) {
                    try {

                        $review->setEntityId($review->getEntityIdByCode(Review::ENTITY_PRODUCT_CODE))
                                ->setEntityPkValue($product->getId())
                                ->setStatusId(Review::STATUS_PENDING)
                                ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                ->setStoreId($this->storeManager->getStore()->getId())
                                ->setStores([$this->storeManager->getStore()->getId()])
                                ->save();


                        foreach ($rating as $ratingId => $optionId) {
                            $this->ratingFactory->create()
                                    ->setRatingId($ratingId)
                                    ->setReviewId($review->getId())
                                    ->setCustomerId($this->customerSession->getCustomerId())
                                    ->addOptionVote($optionId, $product->getId());
                        }
                        print_r($optionId);
                        $review->aggregate();
                        $message[] = __('You submitted your review for moderation.');
                        $status = 'success';
                    } catch (\Exception $e) {
                        $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                        $message[] = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                        $status = 'failed';
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->reviewSession->setFormData($data);
                    if (is_array($validate)) {
                        foreach ($validate as $errorMessage) {
                            $message[] = $errorMessage;
                        }
                    } else {
                        $message[] = __('We can\'t post your review right now.');
                    }
                    $status = 'failed';
                }
            }
        }

        $resultJson = $this->_resultJsonFactory->create()
                ->setData([
            'messages' => $message,
            'status' => $status,
        ]);


        return $resultJson;

    }
```

Comment: Is there any need to call the parent __construct method in child  __construct method : parent::__construct($context);

Comment: Yes , Because I need to use json resultfactory to return result to js

Comment: you can use json resultfactory without use of parent::__construct($context); | Once comment this code parent::__construct($context) in __construct method and compile the code again and check now.

Comment: I have solved my error by calling its parent constructor  without constructor it shows an error

Answer (score 0):

Use this construct method in your controller.

```
  public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context, JsonFactory $resultJsonFactory
    )
    {
        $this->_resultJsonFactory = $resultJsonFactory;

    }
```

Comment: Nope, It shows same error

Comment: Have you hit this command : php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: yes,  even after it shows same error